# iOS - Comparing 2 Arrays and Objects in an array - Logic Issue

Tags: objective-c, iphone, nsset

I have an `NSArray` which contains `Person` objects.

This person object contains the following;

```
> Name 
> Age 
> School 
> Address 
> Telephone_Number
```

Later on i will be setting values to this person object, like `person.Name=@"Jemmy";` (but i will not be setting other attributes, Age, School etc.).

I have an `NSArray` called `personArray`, and it contains 1000 person object records in it. Now i need to Filter out all the objects that contains the `Name` `Jemmy`. How can i do this ?

What i was thinking of doing is;

```
NSMutableArray *arrayThatContainAllPersonObjects = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:personArray];
[arrayThatContainAllPersonObjects removeObjectsInArray:arrayWeAddedTheName];
```

But, what i will get is, an array that doesn't have my filter results. Anyway this might not be the correct approach. I believe we could use `NSSets`, `UNIONS` to solve this.

note:Some might say that this is a duplicate question, but i have searched so much on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use an NSPredicate with NSArray's `filteredArrayUsingPredicate`. Something like this:

```
NSArray *filteredArray = [personArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name = \"Jemmy\""]];
```

Comment: But Name ,Age,School are objects of the Person object. So could i compare an attribute of an object which is part of an array ?

Comment: Yes. See the Predicate Programming Guide (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/predicates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001789) for details. `filteredArrayUsingPredicate` applies the `NSPredicate` to each member of the array, and gives you an array with only the elements matching the predicate. The NSPredicate I gave will match a Person *person if person.name=@"Jemmy".

Answer (score 3):

If the Jemmy's are all identical the easy option is

```
  NSArray * cleanArray = [arrayWithAll removeObjectIdenticalTo:jemmyPerson];
```

If that is not the case (they are called Jemmy - but have different schools or whatever) you are down to

```
   NSArray * cleanArray = [arrayWithAll filterUsingPredicate:jemmyPredicate];
```

or similar with a block/iteration. The predicate can be constructed with something like:

```
   NSPredicate jemmyPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == \"jemmy\"];
```

or

```
    NSPredicate jemmyPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings){
           return [evaluatedObject.Name isEqual:@"Jemmy"];
    }];
```

consult the predicate page for more details.

Comment: What is the purpose of adding it within a block ?

Comment: that lets you write more complex logic easier - though if it is simple - I'd stick with predicates.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `NSArray's` `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` function and write a custom [predicate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/predicates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001798-SW1) to evaluate the objects in your array.

Comment: Can i compare an attribute (`name`) of an object (`person`) which is part of an array (`arrayThatContainAllPersonObjects `) ?

Comment: Yes, you can evaluate virtually every parameter. Read the documentation I linked and you'll learn how.