# Check that the contents of one NSArray are all in another array

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, collections, nsarray

I have one `NSArray` with names in string objects like this:`@[@"john", @"smith", @"alex", 
@"louis"]`, and I have another array that contains lots of names. How can I check that all the objects in the first array are in the second?

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9178585/comparing-2-arrays-and-objects-in-an-array-logic-issue

Answer (score 21):

`NSSet` has the functionality that you are looking for.

If we disregard performance issues for a moment, then the following snippet will do what you need in a single line of code:

```
BOOL isSubset = [[NSSet setWithArray: array1] isSubsetOfSet: [NSSet setWithArray: mainArray]];
```

Comment: I think this is by far the best solution out there. I forgot about NSSet totally.

Comment: @PraveenS: I agree with you :)

Comment: best solution indeed :) +1

Answer (score 3):

Use this code..

```
NSArray *temp1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"john",@"smith",@"alex",@"loui,@"Jac", nil];
NSArray *temp2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"john",@"smith",@"alex",@"loui,@"Rob", nil];

NSMutableSet *telephoneSet = [[NSMutableSet alloc] initWithArray:temp1] ;
NSMutableSet *telephoneSet2 = [[NSMutableSet alloc] initWithArray:temp2];


[telephoneSet intersectSet:telephoneSet2];

 NSArray *outPut = [telephoneSet allObjects];
 NSLog(@"%@",outPut);
```

output array contains:

```
"john","smith","alex","loui
```

as per your requirement.

Comment: The OP wants to CHECK the contents exists in the other array. Not create a new array. How is this the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Run a loop and use `isEqualToStiring` to verify whether array1 objects exists in mainArray.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the concept of `[NSArray containsObject:]`, where your objects will be from your array1 like you say "john","smith","alex","loui"

Answer (score 0):

```
int num_of_matches = 0;
for(NSString *name in mainArray)
{
      if(array1 containsObject:name){
      num_of_matches++;
     }
}
if(num_of_matches == [array1 count]{
      // All objects present
}else {
      // Matched number is equal of number_of_matches
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to check if all objects from array1 are in mainArray, you should just use `NSSet`
e.g.

```
BOOL isSubset = [[NSSet setWithArray:array1] isSubsetOfSet:[NSSet setWithArray:mainArray]]
```

if you need to check which objects are in mainArray, you should take a look at `NSMutableSet`

```
NSMutableSet *array1Set = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:array1];
[array1Set intersectSet:[NSSet setWithArray:mainArray]];
//Now array1Set contains only objects which are present in mainArray too
```

Answer (score 0):

Use NSArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate: method. Its really fast to find out similar types of object in both arrays

```
NSPredicate *intersectPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF IN %@", otherArray];
NSArray *intersectArray = [firstArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:intersectPredicate];
```

From above code intersect array gives you same objects which are in other array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way;

```
NSArray *mainArray=@[@"A",@"B",@"C",@"D"];
NSArray *myArray=@[@"C",@"x"];

BOOL result=YES;
for(id object in myArray){
    if (![mainArray containsObject:object]) {
        result=NO;
        break;
    }
}
NSLog(@"%d",result); //1 means contains, 0 means not contains
```

Comment: Yes, I copied from you  :D

Comment: Grr arrg! You make me SO angry sometimes and I feel like I can't even trust or talk to you anymore! ^^

Comment: @Filip: Dont worry a lot of other friends you will make here :p

Answer (score -1):

```
 NSArray *array1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a", @"u", @"b", @"v", @"c", @"f", nil];
    NSMutableArray *mainArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"a", @"u", @"I", @"G", @"O", @"W",@"Z",@"C",@"T", nil];
    int j=0;
    for(int i=0; i < mainArray.count; i++)
    {
        if (j < array1.count)
        {
            for( j=0; j <= i; j++)
            {
                if([[mainArray objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:[array1 objectAtIndex:j]] )
                {
                    NSLog(@"%@",[mainArray objectAtIndex:i]);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```