# How to check array value not exist in another array

Tags: ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray

I have two different NSMutabelArray ArrOne and ArrTwo. Letsay ArrOne = A, B, C and D ArrTwo = C, D, X and Y. So i need to check if the value of ArrTwo is same as ArrOne and remove item from ArrTwo if it is not same as in ArrOne. In this case, i have to remove X and Y from ArrTwo. Please give me an idea.

Comment: Where is the problem? Can't you just loop through ArrTwo and then check if every element is in ArrOne and if not just delete it?

Comment: Try this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15269497/1635315). This works for me. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution and it works

```
for (int i=0; i< arrTwo.count; i++)
{ 
    if(![arrOne containsObject:[arrTwo objectAtIndex:i]])
    {
         //do action
         NSLog(@"do delete %@",[arrTwo objectAtIndex:i]);
     }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
NSMutableSet *set = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:arrOne];
[set intersectSet:[NSSet setWithAray:arrTwo];
return [set allObjects];
```

Comment: +1, but you didnt completely answer the question. You need to add `[ArrTwo removeObjectsInArray:[set allObjects]];` as well.

Comment: This will only return intersect value. How can I know which one I should delete.

Comment: @bobShawal, You can use `[ArrTwo removeObjectsInArray:[set allObjects]];` after the above code instead of replace. Or else check the answer which will also work for you.

Comment: The answer is correct. If he removes the values in the set from arrTwo he gets the an array containing the values that ARE NOT in arrOne. But that's not what the user asked.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with indexesOfObjectsPassingTest, like this:

```
    NSMutableArray *a = [@[@"A",@"B",@"C",@"D"] mutableCopy];
    NSMutableArray *b = [@[@"C",@"D",@"X",@"Y"] mutableCopy];

    NSIndexSet *indxs = [b indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(NSString *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        return ![a containsObject:obj];
    }];

    [b removeObjectsAtIndexes:indxs];
```