# Get the opposite of intersection between array A and array B

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview

quick question. I have two NSMutableArray:

```
Array 1: [A,B,C,D,E,F];
Array 2: [B,E,F];
```

Note that Array 2 is always subset of Array 1 - meaning objects that exist is Array 2, definitely exist is Array 1 as well.

So what I want is to build an array that contain the objects that are **NOT** in Array 2. Like so

```
Array 3: [A,C,D];
```

I've tried using relative complement as outlined in [this post](http://ronnqvist.tumblr.com/post/28347240420/mini-tip-array-intersections-and-differences) but the resulting array is basically the same as Array 1. It doesn't eliminate the objects that exist in Array 2.

I also tried the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15330261/130785) as well, but still not getting what I want. Unless i'm really doing something very obviously wrong.

Using NSPredicate is much preferable, I guess. But I'm open to ideas and hints.

Note: Just for context, i'm doing this to update my UITableView, basically for data filtering purposes.

Thanks!

---

**UPDATE**

So all the answers given so far actually works with simple set of dummy data for me. But when I tested with my real data, the Array 3 that are created is still the same as the Array 1. So, I'm going to give more info about my stuff.

Both arrays are `NSMutablArray` that store dictionary objects. I'm actually using Parse.com, so the objects in both arrays are [PFObject](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#objects-classes/iOS) (which is just NSObject, if I'm not mistaken). I don't know how does this affect anything, but yeah, seems to not be working.

Here is a [screenshot from the console](http://cl.ly/UNWD) when I try to step through the process.

Thanks for the help so far guys.

Comment: You totally changed the question. You should edit it and explain with what criteria you want to filter the array, in particular which key you want to compare.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need to go down the predicate route here, you know explicitly what you want to do, and can be expressed with simple, native APIs.

```
NSMutableArray *mArray3 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:array1];
[mArray3 removeObjectsInArray:array2];

NSArray* array3 = [mArray3 copy];
```

An important thing to note:

> `removeObjectsInArray:`
>
> This method assumes that all elements in otherArray respond to hash and isEqual:.

For an object to be deemed equal, they need to response to `hash` and `isEqual:`, and for those values to match between two equal objects. A good article regarding equality [can be read here](http://nshipster.com/equality/).

If `PFObject` simply inherits from NSObject, then the equality checking will be very basic.  It will simply check for equality by asking "Are these objects the same object, based on location in memory?". This probably explains why your dummy data works, but the real data does not.

You'll need to subclass PFObject to make it aware of the contents. This means you can override `hash` and `isEqual:` to provide a more reasonable statement of equality. For example, "Are these objects the same object, based on the value of the 'name' property". It's up to you to define what makes objects equal.

Comment: It works with a simple dummy data when I try it out, but not working with my real data. I updated the question with more information, if it helps. Maybe you can provide more insight. Thanks!

Comment: Your real data isn't being deemed 'equal'. I'll update the answer, but basically you need to ensure the values from `hash` and `isEqual:` match for objects that are equal.

Comment: Thanks for the extra information. I'll try it out. But since the original question is considered solved, I'll accept your answer since it's definitely the easiest.

Answer (score 1):

WDUK's answer is probably the way to go since it's simpler and requires only one new object (plus a copy of that). However, if you like discrete math, `NSMutableSet` allows you to perform set operations. That is, another (overly complicated, however, very descriptive) answer to your question is:

```
// convert arrays to sets. 
// since array2 is always a subset of array1, we don't need to create a union set.
NSMutableSet *set1 = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:array1];
NSSet *set2 = [NSSet setWithArray:array2];

// find intersecting objects
NSMutableSet *intersection = [NSMutableSet setWithSet:set1];
[intersection intersectSet:set2];

// remove intersecting objects (result: your desired set)
[set1 minusSet:intersection];

NSArray *nonIntersectingObjects = [set1 allObjects];
```

As WDUK suggests, your problem is easily solved with an `NSMutableArray`. However, when similar, but more complex, problems arise, set operations might provide an simpler and more elegant solution.

Comment: I initially thought this, but the process has the ability to remove ordering, something which is a core property of arrays.

Comment: True and potentially a very important fact (that `NSSet`'s per definition are unordered).

Comment: There is NSOrderedSet for this.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri Still, arrays allow duplicates. That may be a requirement here, so unless the question is clarified, we can't assume order and/or duplication is irrelevant.

Comment: Just to answer the question, no, the order is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it using a predicate here's the way to do it:

```
NSArray* array1= @[@'A',@'B',@'C',@'D',@'E',@'F'];
NSArray* array2= @[@'B',@'E',@'F'];
NSPredicate* predicate= [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"not(self in %@)",array2];
NSArray* array3=[array1 filteredArrayUsingPredicate: predicate];
```

`SELF` represents the evaluated object in the array. The `IN` operator can be used to check if any object is inside a collection, here is some reference: [Predicate programming guide / aggregate operations](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-215891)

Comment: This one also works with a simple dummy data when I try it out, but not working with my real data. I updated the question with more information, if it helps. Maybe you can provide more insight. Thanks!